# Windows web server 2008 fatally crashing daily

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to server issues. So I apologise in advance if this is something simple.

I have a 1and1 cloud server running windows web server 2008.

Recently this has begun to fatally crash near enough daily.

In order to get working I have had to restart the machine through the one and one control panel.

Speaking to the limited support they have told me the other vms on the cluster seem stable and so it must be an issue woth the software.

I have tried trawling through the event log but I can't see anything relevant? (I maybe looking in the wrong area??)

Could some tell me where I should be looking in the event viewer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an application/software crash, you may see events in the `Application` log.

For operating system events (BSODs/bugchecks, ASRs) you will see events in the `System` log.

For IIS (Internet Information Services) logs, see this [link](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/logfile) for details.

To view all events with a level of `Warning` and above (`Warning, Error, Critical`), look under `Custom Views\Administrative Events` in the event log.